# Unable to install ukuu kernel updater

Tags: kernel, 18.04

I was following this tutorial: [Upgrade Kernel on Ubuntu 18.04 – Linux Hint](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/), but when it came to installing ukuu, it gave a bunch of dependency errors

```
$ sudo apt-get install ukuu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700-generic : Depends: linux-modules-4.17.0-041700-generic but it is not installable
 ukuu : Depends: aptitude
        Depends: aria2 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: curl
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 5):

As of January 2019 UKUU now [requires a license](https://teejeetech.in/2019/01/20/ukuu-v19-01/#more-483). The teejee2008 ppa no longer includes the ukuu package, so if you try using that you will get the following error:

> E: Unable to locate package ukuu

Instead you will have to visit https://teejeetech.in/ukuu/ to purchase a license

Answer (score 5):

Go to https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu/releases and download the .deb version according to your CPU platform (64 or 32 bit).

Install and enjoy it.

That's the only way to install that still works.

Comment: Thank you!It's work for me in Ubuntu -18.04

Answer (score 1):

**You should have special requirements to use newest kernel (for example due to newest hardware). Usually using official kernels from Ubuntu repositories is enough and fits to all needs. It is the most universal, stable and secure solution. Using kernels from UKUU you may get system instability (such as crashes and lower uptime).**

As your APT is failing then fix it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-unsigned-4.17.0-041700-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-modules-4.17.0-041700-generic
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

**If you really known what are you doing then continue with UKUU as written below.**

You should install UKUU as recommended on [official GitHub page](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu#ubuntu-based-distributions-ubuntu-linux-mint-elementary-etc) (not from third-party site).

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
```

Then launch it from dash or by `ukuu-gtk`.

Comment: As probably evidenced by the question itself, I don't exactly know what I'm doing. I'm making all sorts of power consumption improvements. Thanks for the warning!